# A blinking text with React using the CSS property visibility

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to code a blinking text that blinks every second
using React throw the CSS property (visibility),
I want to implement it in this exact approach,
here is what I want to do:

Where is the mistake ? I also tried setTimeout but it didn't work as well.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Blink(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState("hidden");

  useEffect(() => {

    setInterval(() => {

      setState("visible");
      console.log("changed");

    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval();
  }, [state]);

  return <span style={{ visibility: state }}>{props.children}</span>;

}


function App() {
  return <Blink>Hello World!</Blink>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setInterval doesn't alternate the state between "visible" and "hidden". All it does it set the state to "visible" over and over again. You need to take the current state into account. The easiest way, I think, would be to make it a boolean (`useState(false)`) and then in the setInterval, have it `setState(!state)`.

Then all you need to do is change the style to `{{ visibility: state ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to clear the state (toggle visible/hidden). I think you should try something like this:

```
setState(state == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible')
```